# Compilation issue with React, Typescript and Material-UI 4

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Suddenly, my entire build has collapsed and won't build. I reset the project several days ago with a fresh create-react app build, and it was fine for a bit, and then yesterday - similar problem with a different error:

```
Failed to compile.

TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; xsDown: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HiddenProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HiddenProps'.
    208 |                     {studentName(x)} &lt;{x.student}&gt;
    209 |                 </Box>
  > 210 |                 {!locked && <Hidden xsDown={true}><Box><RemoveButton deleteClickHandler={deleteClickHandler} x={x}/></Box></Hidden>}
        |                              ^^^^^^
    211 |                 {locked &&
    212 |                 <Box>
    213 |                     <Tooltip title="Locked"><Lock/></Tooltip>


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've already stripped out some libraries I was using in small place that I suspected of causing conflicting types declarations, but, I'm still getting this problem, and at this point, I'm totally stuck.

Package.json isn't very complex:

```
  "name": "****Redacted****",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-table/core": "^4.3.39",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.19.6",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.6",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.26.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/dateformat": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.8",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js-typescript": "^1.22.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "dateformat": "^4.6.3",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.5",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.1.0",
    "react-dnd-touch-backend": "14.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: what is `Hidden` if its component show the code as well kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beleive this is because you've updated to React 18 (specifically, `"@types/react": "^18.0.0",`).

[This pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210) talks about what has changed.

Because the issue stems from Material Ui 4 component, most likely you'll need to do one of the following:

1. upgrade to Mui5
2. downgrade to React 17
3. wait for [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59751) to be merged, that seems to alliviate the issue that you have.

(Also, `<Hidden/>` from MUI4 [does implement](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/c1936ad4764f84f9e1788af79daef7280cc7b4da/packages/mui-material/src/Hidden/Hidden.d.ts) children with `children?: React.ReactNode;` just like first link mentions)

Comment: It's weird, because the version I have in Material-ui 4.12.4 doesn't have that. I will try to downgrade to react 17 here, maybe that'll help. I thought I tried that, but... maybe not properly

Comment: Now I get a different error telling me <Box> cannot be used as a JSX Component :/.

Comment: For me it was becasue materail-ui/core@4.12.4 is pulling in @types/react-transistion-group@4.4.5 which is in turn pullin in @types/react@18.0.15 If you run npm ls @types/react you can see whats pulling it in.